# Most RAM for an MCU in a DIP package

Tags: microcontroller, ram

So far the most RAM laden MCU I have found in a hobbyist friendly DIP package is a dsPIC33FJ128GP802, which has 16KB, and the Parallax Propeller, which has 32KB. But does anyone know of chips with more memory in said packages? This is only for prototyping, I also need surface mount chips for production.

Comment: This isn't any better than the PIC, but AVR makes the ATMEGA1284P (128KB flash, 16KB RAM) in a 40-pin DIP: http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=ATMEGA1284P-PU-ND

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you only need the DIP format for prototyping, use some adapter boards and prototype with those. With a steady hand you should be able to solder SOIC and TQFP parts.

This kind of thing:

[image: TQFP to DIP Adapter]
<sup>Image from [here](http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/product_info.php?products_id=2200117)</sup>

Comment: +1 - It's a good idea, but actual DIP's are far easier to work with. Is it me, or does that adapter not have all pins broken out?

Comment: looks like a bunch are routed on the back.  No idea why, all they had to do was put the QFP at a 45deg angle and they could have routed it all on 1 side.

Comment: Yeah, but where do the pins from the top left to the top right go? There's a whole bunch that aren't connected... (as all pins are used up.) Same on the bottom.

Comment: @Thomas O, as @Mark said, they're routed on the back, see the circular vias connecting them to the other side

Comment: @thomas I guess i don't see what your talking about, there are obvious vias for 8 pins on the top and the traces are clear on the back.  Weirdest thing i see here is the pad under the IC with traces out to those side pins.  I guess its so if you have a QFP with a pad under it you could connect to it, but there are exposed via's under the IC.  Unless you were really careful with the size of the pad under the QFP i would think it would be really easy to short those vias out.

Comment: @Mark - Funny, I'm usually really trying hard to get the pad under the QFP to make solid contact with the ground pad through the vias/holes...

Answer (score 6):

If you just need extra RAM, and you don't need to address it directly as a memory address (i.e. okay to go through a function call), Microchip makes a [32KB SRAM](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=23K256-I/P-ND) with a 20 MHz SPI interface in an 8-pin DIP (also available as a SMD) for $1.66 in singles, $1 in quantity.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering this, but my application needs speed, and it has interrupts, so the operations might be undefined if the code for writing to the memory gets interrupted mid write... would it write half a word? I couldn't have that.

Comment: @Thomas, assuming you are using SPI interface built into your MCU, your program will be writing and reading SPI registers as atomic operation and you will not use lose any data, even if interrupted.  (You could also implement a SPI handler using interrupts.)  The clocking and writing and reading of the SRAM will be handled by the hardware interface.  Since the MCU is the SPI master, you can't miss data coming from the SRAM.

Comment: As far as speed goes, with a 2 MHz SPI clock (1/10 the rated SRAM speed), it shouldn't take more than 30 us to read or write a byte (even with subroutine overhead), so can write or read 30 bytes/ms, or the entire 32KB in a second.  (I haven't looked at the datasheet, just making some educated guess here.)

Comment: Compared to the MCU's internal RAM that's way too slow. I need to clear 8KB in 1/30th second. The 8KB codes for a frame of video information and it needs to update around ~30 fps. At the moment the MCU can do around about 3000 fps when just clearing the screen, so 3000x faster. Can a dsPIC33FJ128GP802 do SPI at 20 MHz?

Comment: @Thomas, I didn't realize you needed to do a block write of 8KB.  It turns out once you have sent the starting address to the SRAM, you can continue to write bytes sequentially.   So just a 5 MHz SPI clock, assuming you are using the SPI interrupt, would allow you to write around 600 bytes/ms, or 8 KB in about 1/60 of a second, about twice as fast as your requirement.  I wouldn't try to run it any higher than that on a breadboard using DIP's.

Comment: @Thomas, although it is possible to write 8KB to the SRAM in 1/60 of a sec as I discussed in over my last comment, it would probably tie up over half of the processor handling the interrupt, so it might not be a good idea.  Best to find a processor with more RAM for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to update the information below.

> 8-bit AVR: ATmega1284(p), 16kB RAM, 128kB flash, DIP40
>
> 32-bit AVR: None
>
> 8-bit PIC: PIC18F(2/4)7K42, 8kB RAM, 128kB flash, SDIP28/DIP40
>
> 16-bit PIC: dsPIC33EP512xxx02, 48kB RAM, 512kB flash, SDIP28
>
> 32-bit PIC: PIC32MXxxxF256B, 64kB RAM, 256kB flash, SDIP28
>
> 32-bit ARM: LPC1114FN28, 4kB RAM, 32kB flash, DIP28

Last updated January 4, 2018